# Access Database Engine won't install

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, sql-server

I have Office products through Office 365 and a 64 bit system. I've been trying to install Access Database Engine so I can import data into SQL server from a macro-enabled Excel doc (.xlsm), but when I try to run the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe, it gives me an error saying I'm trying to install a 32-bit feature/program when I have 64-bit Office installed. So I tried installing AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe, and it gives me an error saying I'm trying to install a 64-bit thing when I have 32-bit Office installed.

Clearly both of those things can't be true. How can I install either of these so I can move forward with the data import into SQL Server? What other things should I try? Any advice/knowledge on this subject would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I had to run the .exe through Command Prompt, with the `/quiet` switch tacked onto the end.

> If you have an Office 365 subscription, you may see an error message
>   when you run the installer. The error indicates that you can't install
>   the download side by side with Office click-to-run components. To
>   bypass this error message, run the installation in quiet mode by
>   opening a Command Prompt window and running the .EXE file that you
>   downloaded with the /quiet switch. For example:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<user_name>\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet
> ```

Source: [Import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Ramhound fine with me; thanks for improving my answer!